# slideToggle() not working properly

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, slidetoggle

I added a slideToggle() effect in my page but it doesn't work properly.

```
$j(".fields_toggle").click(function() {
    $j(this).toggleClass("closed").next('.toggle_container').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Clicking the toggle-trigger gets the slide-content sliding-down and then sliding-up immediatelly, without clicking it again.

```
<div class="onoffswitch right fields_toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" name="myonoffswitch2" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch2" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label " for="myonoffswitch2"> <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
<span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>

    </label>
</div>
<div class="row toggle_container">
    <input type="text" id="dpd1" value="" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Arrival">
    <input type="text" id="dpd2" value="" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Departure">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ktsixit/kp533/

The reason for this is beacause I'm using the checkbox-radio-switch.css file (included in [ExtendBootstrap](http://extendbootstrap.com/)). It's just some css that gives a switch look on checkboxes.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I added `e.preventDefault` and we're nearly there [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kp533/4/)

Comment: It's clear to see that the click event is firing off more than once, because there are two slide actions going on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I got this working properly.

I gave 2 `id` to related `divs`

```
<div class="onoffswitch right fields_toggle" id="btn_for_toggle">
```

and

```
 <div class="row toggle_container" id="form_elements">
```

and in javascript part:

```
jQuery("#myonoffswitch2").on("click", function () {
    jQuery("#form_elements").toggle("slow");
    jQuery("#btn_for_toggle").toggleClass("closed");
});
```

See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hp6WZ/)

Comment: how come your answer gets 3 upvotes, and I got the answer first, and it worked 20mins before yours..... this system is so flawed

Comment: I really don't have a clue, but my solution looks simpler imho. Still maybe he accepts your answer, I don't know

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got this far with the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kp533/5/)

I just keep track with:

```
var on = true;
```

I also hooked into the change event, because it seemed that it went `click` -> `change` -> `click`

```
$j(".fields_toggle").on('change', function (e) {
     console.log(2);   
     e.preventDefault();
    on = !on;
});
```

I think this gets what you need?

Comment: @ktsixit I just checked, I'm running chrome, its working perfectly... what browser you running?

Comment: I'm running firefox 28. I checked it on Chrome and it works fine, but it doen't work on firefox. I'm using firefox, and I saw your fiddle not working, that's why I didn't accept your answer as the solution... sorry about that

Comment: @ktsixit to be honest the other guys is better :)